# Display an External List in a DataView webpart

Tags: data-view-web-part, xslt, external-content-type, external-list

My scenario is as follows:

- I have a dataview wp which currently displays list items (from ECT).
- In the DataView wp I filter the data according to a parameter passed in from another wp.

The current list data looks like this:

```
ID, ParentID, Name        Comments
================================
1   Null      Test        blah
2   1         Test_1      clah
3   1         Test_2      dlah
4   2         Test_1_1    plah
5   4         Test_1_1_1  poo
```

Currently, the list in the view is filtered as below:

```
/rsQueryResponse/Row/Rows[@ID=$ParamValue]
```

What I hope to achieve is that, if an ID of say 1, is passed to the dataview, then it will show comments from all the children also.

Since it does not look like its possible to do any sort of complex data manipulation within the xsl, I thought I'd pick your brains to see if there is any other viable solution.

Thanks,

KS

Comment: Couldn't you just change the internal binding to something like /rsQueryResponse/Row/Rows[@ID=$ParamValue or @ParentID=$ParamValue]?

Comment: Well that wouldn't work for a hierarchy with more than one level.

Comment: Misinterpreted the data. It will need some custom xslt to achieve. You'd need to pass the parameter through a template to get the parent, then keep passing it through another template to build child and grandchildren nodes

Comment: How do I query the same data from another template - do I just pass the rows - could you possibly provide a small code sample. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that the better way to do this was to do the hierarchy grouping in SQL and then use a Business Data List to display the data with a custom xsl for formatting. The ECT is set up with stored procedures.
Thanks!